# I do I have socket file from my program's single socket() call and it exists in /proc/pid/fd/3 or some number . Now How to open and write to it

Tags: c, linux, file, sockets

I like to write tcp packets to socket file of my program by opening/or not opening(I dont care) and just write packets to it. so my program socket can read packets and proceed with where ever it is in connection. Is it possible in C and Linux

On Man page from linux it says

```
 O_ASYNC
              Enable ...  This
              feature is available only for terminals, pseudoterminals,
              sockets[SO ITS AVAILABLE TO OPEN A SOCKET --HOW?], and (since Linux 2.6) pipes and FIFOs.  See
              fcntl(2)[DO I NEED TO USE fcntl] for further details.  See also BUGS, below.
```

The above is for open system call in Linux on Man page

So I like to know how to open socket file on my system in /proc/my_pid/fd/3 or any number. Does anyone know this please tell

Comment: Nur fully sure what you are trying to do and what O_ASYNC should have to do with this. But a file descriptor (socket, file, whatever) is represented by an integer - in your case 3. Just use this integer inside read, write, recv, send .. . Note that the meaning of this integer is specific to the process itself, i.e. one cannot simply use the same integer in another process and hope that it will represent the same.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am not sure u are following what I like to ask. I specifically mentioned I need to `open file or not open but just write to it`. Since it's a file there must be a way to write to it in my case I need to write data which are packets. And it's separate program that I am accessing file descriptor in some my code. One is client and other I am emulating server. Client use connect function and server that simply open this file and read packets. This is what I need. I know it's possible so this question. What do u mean by `Nur fully what you are trying to do & what O_ASYNC..`

Comment: See also this link it's possible https://askubuntu.com/a/372737/1362216

Comment: "how to open socket file on my system in /proc/my_pid/fd/3 or any" : There are "no files" in /proc/. .... The virtual file system /proc/ allows you to read information. Nothing else. ..... Please do `$ du /proc/` to know that "the files" are zero Bit.

Comment: The question you link to is about UNIX domain sockets, what you have here is instead just a virtual filesystem which allows to view what file descriptors are open. I doubt that it is possible to implement some client server communication by just creating a file descriptor in one process and then writing to it through the proc file system from another process. I'm still not sure what you want to achieve at the end - either you are just curious if this is possible or you describe the Y part of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), in which case it would be useful to know the real problem X.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich actually for last number of days I was simulating tcp listening port just reading and writing packets along with iphdr and struct tcphdr.i am composing correct Syn+ Ack packet& pass wireshark checking to be valid packets but my tcp client socket keep sending SYN packets and ignoring my Syn+ Ack packets.so I thought if I find the client socket file and just write my SYN + ACK packet to that file then maybe my client will stop emitting Syn packets and finally send Ack packet to my simulated listening port.am getting ip packets in simulated port listening code using TUN interface

Comment: I hope last comment help u understand why it's need. And I also know there is file relate to each socket starting with s with ls command

Comment: @KnudLarsen please see my second last comment for explanation why I need this. If u can tell